# C - WSADATA Type could not be resolved but libraries are added

Tags: c, mingw

I got the type could not be resolved error for WSADATA in my program even though I added the wsock32 library in mingw c linker libraries section.

Here's the code, any ideas?

```
#if defined WIN32
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#else
#define closesocket close
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    #if defined WIN32
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSAData wsaData;
    int iResult =
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("Error at WSAStartup()\n");
    return 0;
    }
    #endif
    int MySocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    




    //process



    closesocket(MySocket);
    #if defined WIN32
    WSACleanup();
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: the double include for winsock and winsock2 is there because I tried to fix the problem by adding the second library, it didn't work

Comment: This problem is a typo/not reproducible, but you don't need to include `winsock.h`; only `winsock2.h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type names in C are case sensitive. So, in place of:

```c
WSAData wsaData;
```

use:

```c
WSADATA wsaData; // Note: The type name is ALL CAPS!
```